# Append HTML code to a existing Razor section

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to append the HTML code to a existing razor section?

Below is my scenario:

My _layout.cshtml contains something like this:

```
@RenderSection("BottomSection", required: false)
```

and in one of the view - _article.cshtml, I have defined the section like below:

```
@section BottomSection
{
 <script src='~/Scripts/module/article_details.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
 <script src='~/Scripts/module/modal.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
 @MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.ExtraStuff)   
}
```

and in a partial view named _counter.cshtml, which is used by the above view; I would like to add more HTML code to the same section i.e., BottomSection.

I tried declaring the BottomSection section again in the partial view:

```
@section BottomSection{
<text>More data</text>
}
```

But it didn't worked out.

Is there any way to achieve this - dynamically append more code to an already defined razor section in MVC 4? 
Please note that the partial view doesn't expects any data from the parent view/model.
 And I'm using MVC 4 with .Net Framework 4.0/VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to append stuff to sections (in fact I would like to know that myself), but I know a trick that might produce similar result. Instead of using sections one can use TempData. TempData is a lot like ViewBag, but once a variable is set it'll live there for current user until one tries to access it again (it can live through a few successive requests for current user, so extra caution is advised). Below is an example of how it could be used.

In layout:

```
@Html.Raw(new MvcHtmlString((string)TempData["BottomSection"]));
```

In the view:

```
@{
    var bottomSection = (string)TempData["BottomSection"];
    if (bottomSection == null)
    {
        bottomSection = "";
    }
    bottomSection += "<script src='~/Scripts/module/article_details.js' type='text/javascript'></script>\n";
    bottomSection += "<script src='~/Scripts/module/modal.js' type='text/javascript'></script>\n";
    bottomSection += Model.ExtraStuff + "\n";
    TempData["BottomSection"] = bottomSection;
}
```

In the partial view:

```
@{
    var bottomSection = (string)TempData["BottomSection"];
    if (bottomSection == null)
    {
        bottomSection = "";
    }
    bottomSection += "More data";
    TempData["BottomSection"] = bottomSection;
}
```

This can be further improved by writing a helper for those pseudo sections and\or by moving the contents of the sections a separate partials (look below).

```
bottomSection += Html.Partial("_StuffToAddToSection").ToString();
```

---

Helper class:

```
public static class PseudoSectionsHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString AppendToPseudoSection<T>(this TempDataDictionary TempData, string sectionName, T model, Func<T, HelperResult> content, bool addNewLineCharacter = true)
        where T : class
    {
        return AppendToPseudoSection(TempData, sectionName, content(model).ToString(), addNewLineCharacter);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString AppendToPseudoSection(this TempDataDictionary TempData, string sectionName, MvcHtmlString content, bool addNewLineCharacter = true)
    {
        return AppendToPseudoSection(TempData, sectionName, content.ToString(), addNewLineCharacter);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString AppendToPseudoSection(this TempDataDictionary TempData, string sectionName, string content, bool addNewLineCharacter = true)
    {
        var section = (string)TempData[sectionName];
        if (section == null)
        {
            section = "";
        }
        else if (addNewLineCharacter)
        {
            section += "\n";
        }
        section += content;
        TempData[sectionName] = section;
        // We return empty MvcHtmlString to be able to use this helper inline (without declaring code block @{ some code... } in view)
        return new MvcHtmlString("");
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString PseudoSection(this TempDataDictionary TempData, string sectionName)
    {
        var section = (string)TempData[sectionName];
        return new MvcHtmlString(section);
    }
}
```

Use example

In layout add:

```
@TempData.PseudoSection("BottomSection")
```

In view:

```
@TempData.AppendToPseudoSection("BottomSection", Model, @<text>
    <script src='~/Scripts/module/article_details.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='~/Scripts/module/modal.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    @MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.ExtraStuff)
</text>)
```

or

```
@{
    TempData.AppendToPseudoSection("BottomSection", Model, @<text>
        <script src='~/Scripts/module/article_details.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='~/Scripts/module/modal.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        @MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.ExtraStuff)
    </text>);
}
```

or even

```
@TempData.AppendToPseudoSection("BottomSection", Html.Partial("BottomSectionScriptsAndStuff"))
```

And in partial:

```
@TempData.AppendToPseudoSection("BottomSection", "More data")
```

Comment: Using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items in place of TempData might be an even better idea, as TempData lives as long as you don't read it which can possibly lead to odd situations (like a section you didn't render on one page, renders on another).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe i dont understand your question but why you dont using nested partial views???

for example :

PartialView1

```
`<script src='~/Scripts/module/article_details.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
 <script src='~/Scripts/module/modal.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
 @MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.ExtraStuff)
 @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialView2",Model.ExtraStuff );}`
```

PartialView2

```
`<text>More data</text>`
```

Comment: Having multiple partial views will resolve the issue. But, this will end up having lot of partial view files for me - defying the purpose for dynamic approach.

Answer (score -3):

Using Ajax you can load the partial view and can render in your target division.

Try using jquery ajax

```
      $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 20000,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (_results) {
                $("#TargetDiv").html(_results);
            },
            error: function (_results) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please Tell why this solution is wrong. I have tried the same for appending the newly generated html to already rendered view

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but this is not I wanted to do. The partial view can add more content/script references etc. Getting the data will add a roundtrip request and till then my page will not work!